# Non blocking sockets with overlapped I/O

Tags: c++, sockets, nonblocking, overlapped-io

I'm trying to work myself through the socket jungle and came across non blocking sockets with overlapped I/O. I have three books at home which only mention this concept but don't really explain it or give me any examples.

So what I'm looking for is an article where this get's explained with an example or just an example I can work myself through. It would be good if this would be for windows but I guess I should be able to transfer it from unix as well.

I don't mind a book as source but I would be glad to avoid another 50$. So far I only found the very basic concept and basic comparisons with other socket models. It's not that I don't understand their concept but I would like to see them in action and maybe get a good explanation of how they work. ( I don't mind long articles at all :) )

Comment: My first thought would be to just understand Overlapped I/O. It has a very specific meaning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapped_I/O Have a read of that article.

Comment: Then you also need to know what a I/O Completation Port is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_output_completion_port

Comment: Any platform independent analysis of sockets in C++ has to include at least a cursory glance at Boost.Asio (in my opinion!) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Comment: Another decent article which explains why it's called *Overlapped* I/O is this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Nick: AFAIK Overlapped I/O is a Windows Specific thing.

Comment: True. I'm just an avid proponent of Boost.Asio! :) Why go to the bother of learning all about Overlapped I/O when you can have such an elegant implementation using ASIO.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: unix has similar asynchronous API's that are just called differently, in any case `boost::asio` wraps all that for you.

Comment: @Tony: IIRC you can actually do specifically Overlapped I/O with Boost.Asio, see [`windows::overlapped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/windows__overlapped_ptr.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase 'non-blocking sockets' usually refers to use of the FIONBIO socket option, which makes a call to read() return immediately even if there is no data ready to read. (It returns with an EWOULDBLOCK error.)

Overlapped I/O is something specific to the Windows API (and not available on UNIX for example). The FIONBIO socket option is *not* used, neither are the traditional Berkeley socket API function calls (read() etc).

(For a POSIX equivalent on Linux, refer to 'man aio' or type man aio into your favourite search engine.)

Now that you understand that 'non-blocking sockets' and 'overlapped I/O' are two different approaches (and not to be mixed), finding helpful articles on each should be much easier.

The MSDN documentation on overlapped I/O is actually very good. If you are doing Windows programming then you really need to be using overlapped I/O for anything where performance and scalability matters. Here's a good starting point:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

(This MSDN article is about pipes, but it is exactly the same using sockets.)

Also, be aware that WaitForMultipleObjects() doesn't scale as well as using I/O completion ports, but get comfortable with the former first.